# Upload an attachment to zendesk with java

Tags: java

I'm trying to upload an attachement to [zendesk](http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/rest_api/attachments.html). From the API documentation you have to use

```
 curl -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/binary" \
--data-binary @file.dat -X POST \
"https://helpdesk.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=myfile.dat&token=                       {optional_token}"
```

I am trying to do the same thing with java. I can upload a file and receive the correct json response. However if I open the file on the zendesk server, the file is not recognized. If I upload the same file with curl from the command line everything is working OK. What am I doing wrong here ? This is my java code I use to upload the file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\zendesk2\\Zendesk\\src\\main\\resources\\scrat.jpg");
    try {
        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("filename", new StringBody(file.getName()));
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, "application/octet-stream");
        multipartEntity.addPart("attachment", fileBody);

        // -u admin:password
        Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "passw");
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

        // -X POST
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://testserver.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json");

        // @ - absolute path
        httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

        // process response
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {
            long len = resEntity.getContentLength();
            if (len != -1 && len < 2048) {
// this result is being parsed with gson....
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            } else {
                // Stream content out
            }
        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //-f, fail silently}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working on a [Java client for Zendesk](https://github.com/cloudbees/zendesk-java-client).

You can upload an attachment using the current *0.0.3-SNAPSHOT* version of the code. I will probably be adding more functionality in the near future.

Here is some sample code with the current way the API works:

```
ZenDesk zd = new ZenDesk.Builder("https://{{your domain}}.zendesk.com")
        .setUsername("...")
        .setToken("...") // or .setPassword("...")
        .build();

byte[] contents = new byte[file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fis);
fis.read(contents);
fis.close();

Attachment.Upload upload = zd.createUpload(file.getName(), "application/binary", contents);

zd.close();
```

Hope this helps (note that the sample code above is not tidying up with respect to exceptions, but should give you the basic way the API works).

Comment: This is not a full example though right? The logical next step is to somehow make the upload available on given ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it took me awhile to work out how to do this and I wanted to share.

1. To attach a file to a ticket it is a 3 step process. Create a ticket
   if one does not exist (I know, it should be obvious) and get the
   ticket id.
2. Create an upload for your particular file type etc. which will return an Upload with a token property.
3. Update the ticket by referencing the ticket id with a comment containing a List of the single token.

`Ticket ticket = zd.createTicket(ticket);
    Attachment.Upload upload = zd.createUpload(fileName, "application/binary", content);
    List tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    tokens.add(upload.getToken());
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setBody("My upload");
    comment.setTokenks(tokens);
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setId(ticketId);
    ticket.setComment(comment);
    zd.upateTicket(ticket);`