# How to integrate zendesk to Android app?

Tags: android, zendesk

I want to implement zendesk to our application.

**i read below link :-**

http://www.zendesk.com/blog/zendesk-for-android-arrives

**after above link I'm go through below link:-**

http://www.zendesk.com/blog/dropbox-support-for-iphone-and-android-apps-pr

**than its show java lib file for android :-**

https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_android_sdk

**and i read this document care fully**

https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_android_sdk/blob/master/README.md

after read this document i m implementing zendesk and its works and shown below image :-

[image]

but after click on send button its shows below msg

[image]

**manifest**

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="zendesk_title"
            android:value="XXXX" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="zendesk_url"
            android:value="abc@xyz.biz.zendesk.com" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="zendesk_description"
            android:value="How may XXXX help you?" />
```

**android:value="abc@xyz.biz.zendesk.com"**  abc@xyz.biz this my login email address on zendesk.

i change `android:value="yoursubdomain.zendesk.com" to` `android:value="abc@xyz.biz.zendesk.com` bcz this link

https://support.zendesk.com/entries/20041133-Lesson-3-Customizing-the-customer-experience-Classic-

**logcat**

```
06-06 11:55:05.937: E/Zendesk(2825): Error while, submit request
06-06 11:55:05.937: E/Zendesk(2825): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://abc@xyz.biz.zendesk.com/requests/mobile_api/create.json
06-06 11:55:05.937: E/Zendesk(2825):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
06-06 11:55:05.937: E/Zendesk(2825):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
06-06 11:55:05.937: E/Zendesk(2825):    at com.zendesk.ZendeskDialog$1.run(ZendeskDialog.java:178)
06-06 11:55:05.937: E/Zendesk(2825):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I know something missing or wrong on email address but nothing found.

i searched a lot but nothing to found any thing so if any one face same problem so please share with solution.

**Problem Solved:-**

first we have to make ur account on it 
https://support.zendesk.com/home and click right hand side button **(Try Zendesk Free)** and create ur id and u get id and put this id to ur manifest.

Works fine....

Answer (score 2):

Zendesk has now a new SDK that you can use
https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/overview

and an open source sample application that showcase the integration
https://github.com/zendesk/sdk_demo_app_android

Full disclaimer : I am working for Zendesk.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata url is wrong it cant be abc@xyz.biz.zendesk.com
it is like below.

```
 <meta-data android:name="zendesk_url" android:value="yoursubdomain.zendesk.com"/>
```

Comment: abc for my name,
xyz for company name,
biz for as like .com

Comment: nothing happend same error with xyz.zendesk.com or abc@xyz.biz.zendesk.com or abc@xyz.zendesk.com

Comment: check this link for implementation  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712814/upload-an-attachment-to-zendesk-with-java

Answer (score 0):

You no need to add their libs.
Rather you can use the REST API for doing your stuff.